# How to distribute the records over mnesia fragments?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

I have two erlang MNESIA nodes running in the cluster.

I have created table by the below properties.

```
mnesia:create_table(vmq_offline_store,[
                {frag_properties,[
                    {node_pool,[node()|nodes()]},
                    {hash_module,verneDB_frag_hash},
                    {n_fragments,8},
                    {n_disc_only_copies,length([node()|nodes()])}]
                },
                {index,[]},{type, bag},
                {attributes,record_info(fields,vmq_offline_store)}]).
```

I could see all the 8 fragments created on the two erlang nodes.

After this,I inserted 50000 records into the table using RPC call from external node.These 50000 records inserted into only vmq_offline_store. Not distributed over all the fragments.

```
vmq_offline_store: with 50000    records occupying 2096701142 bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag2: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag3: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag4: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag5: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag6: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag7: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
vmq_offline_store_frag8: with 0        records occupying 5464     bytes on disc
```

Could you please help me how to distribute the records over the fragments?

Answer (score 1):

It's not enough to create the Mnesia table with fragmentation properties.  Every table operation must explicitly specify the "access module" for fragmented tables, `mnesia_frag`.  This is done by calling the function [`mnesia:activity/4`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#activity-4), instead of calling `mnesia:transaction/1` or using dirty operations.

For example, this code:

```
Fun = fun() -> ... end,
{atomic, Result} = mnesia:transaction(Fun),
```

becomes:

```
Fun = fun() -> ... end,
Result = mnesia:activity(transaction, Fun, [], mnesia_frag),
```

(Note that on errors `mnesia:activity` signals an error instead of returning `{aborted, Reason}`.)

For dirty operations, code like this:

```
mnesia:dirty_write(MyRecord)
```

becomes:

```
mnesia:activity(sync_dirty, mnesia, write, [MyRecord], mnesia_frag)
```

or alternatively:

```
mnesia:activity(sync_dirty, fun() -> mnesia:write(MyRecord) end, [],
                mnesia_frag)
```

That is, *never* use the `mnesia:dirty_*` functions; use the "bare" ones within a dirty activity.